# Help needed in converting a few lines of ruby code to c++!

Tags: c++, ruby, qt, openssl

I have to convert the following code into Qt c++
So I need to understand what these lines to.

@key in this code is a pem key file contents by openssl

```
key = KEY+@key.public_key.to_der
```

1. so i think this is converting that key to der format and then combining it with KEY. 
   is it right?
2. whats does this do? to_sizet(key.size)
   As you can see the function returns [num].pack('V'). But i dont know wht does it do? I mean [num].pavck('V'). what is it?
3. And whats does this mean. key.size is it the strlen of key?

> ```
> def write_crx
>    print "write crx..." if @verbose
>    key = KEY+@key.public_key.to_der
>    File.open(@crx, 'wb') do |file|
>      file << MAGIC
>      file << EXT_VERSION
>      file << to_sizet(key.size)
>      file << to_sizet(@sig.size)
>      file << key
>      file << @sig
>      File.open(@zip, 'rb') do |zip|
>        file << zip.read
>      end
>    end
>    puts "done at \"#{@crx}\"" if @verbose
>  end
>  def to_sizet num
>    return [num].pack('V')
>  end
> ```

**Well I have one more Question. Forgot to add last time.**
*what does this line do?*

```
KEY = %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00).map{|s| s.hex}.pack('C*')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so i think this is converting that key to der format and then combining it with KEY. is it right?

Yes.

> whats does this do? to_sizet(key.size) As you can see the function returns [num].pack('V'). But i dont know wht does it do? I mean [num].pavck('V'). what is it?

Well, just have a look at what the documentation on [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206) says. With the `V` modifier, it just converts the array to a binary representation of a 32 bit unsigned integer type.

> And whats does this mean. key.size is it the strlen of key?

Again, the Ruby documentation helps. [`String#size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001132) is indeed the string length.

> what does this line do?
>
> ```
> KEY = %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00)
>         .map{|s| s.hex}.pack('C*')
> ```

`%(…)` defines an array where each of its entries, separated by whitespace is treated as a separate string. [`%w(one two)` is essentially a shorthand for `["one", "two"]`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UF).

After that, we have to look up (again in the documentation) the meanings of `Array#map` and `String#hex`.

`map` simply applies an operation to each element of an array and creates a new array with the result. The operation is `s.hex` – that is, parse each of the strings as a hexadecimal number.

The result is once again packed, this time using the `C*` operation which, the documentation tells us, converts the numbers into their corresponding (unsigned) 8-bit character codes.

In summary: that line converts the hexadecimal values into a string of their respective characters.

**Afterthought:** you should really install Ruby and play a bit with the interactive Ruby console, `irb`. Keying in the above line already helps a lot:

```
$ irb
>> %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00).map{|s| s.hex}
=> [48, 129, 159, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, 129, 141, 0]
>> %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00).map{|s| s.hex}.pack('C*')
=> "0\201\2370\r\006\t*\206H\206\367\r\001\001\001\005\000\003\201\215\000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It was excellent.
I have one more question, can you please tell what does this line do?
KEY = %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00).map{|s| s.hex}.pack('C*')
of course in ruby!